# Add Gmail Signature usin AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace, workspace

Hi I'm trying to add signatures to Workspace users.
I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936257/how-to-use-the-gmail-api-oauth2-for-apps-script-and-domain-wide-delegation-to/40936258#40936258).
It's works but only with users that doesn't have any signatures and I would like to add new signatures (or override the previous ones). Another things is that it doesn't work for the owner either.
I would appreciate your help.

This is my current code:

```js
function setSignatureTest() {
  var user = {
    primaryEmail: "admin@domain.do",
    name: {
      fullName:'Admin Name',
      familyName:'Admin Last Name',
      givenName:'Admin Name'
    }
  };
  var test = setSignature(user.primaryEmail, user);

  Logger.log('test result: ' + test);

}

function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'domain.com',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;

    var accountsToIgnore = [
      'test@example.com',
      'testtest@example.com'
    ];

    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        if (accountsToIgnore.indexOf(user.primaryEmail) == -1) {
          var userName = user.name.fullName;
          var userEmail = user.primaryEmail;
          var userOrgRole = user.organizations ? user.organizations[0].title : ''
          Logger.log('-- %s (%s) %s', userName, userEmail, userOrgRole);
          Logger.log('%s (%s)', user);
          setSignature(userEmail, user);
        }

      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}

function setSignature(email, userData) {
  var signatureSetSuccessfully = false;
  var authorizationScope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic'];
  
  var service = getDomainWideDelegationService("Gmail: ", authorizationScope, email);

  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    Logger.log("failed to authenticate as user " + email);
    Logger.log(service.getLastError());

    signatureSetSuccessfully = service.getLastError();

    return signatureSetSuccessfully;
  } else {
    Logger.log("successfully authenticated as user " + email);
  }
  
  var signatureTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("signature").getContent();
  var userSig = signatureTemplate
          .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")
          .replace(/{email}/g, userData.primaryEmail)
          .replace(/{firstName}/g, userData.name.givenName)
          .replace(/{lastName}/g, userData.name.familyName)
          .replace(/{jobTitle}/g, userData.organizations ? userData.organizations[0].title : '')
  var resource = { 
    signature: userSig
  };
  
  var requestBody                = {};
  requestBody.headers            = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken(),
    "Accept": "application/json", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  requestBody.contentType        = "application/json";
  requestBody.method             = "PATCH";
  requestBody.payload            = JSON.stringify(resource);
  requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = false;

  var emailForUrl = encodeURIComponent(email);

  var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${email}/settings/sendAs/` + emailForUrl;

  try {
    var setSignatureResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);
    signatureSetSuccessfully = true;
    Logger.log("setSignatureResponse on successful attempt:" + JSON.parse(setSignatureResponse).sendAsEmail);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log("Set signature with HTTP request failed: " + e);
  }
  
  return signatureSetSuccessfully;
}

// these two things are included in the .JSON file that you download when creating the service account and service account key
var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY  = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL = 'SERVICE ACCOUNT CLIENTE EMAIL';

function getDomainWideDelegationService(serviceName, scope, email) {

  Logger.log('starting getDomainWideDelegationService for email: ' + email);

  return OAuth2.createService(serviceName + email)
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL)

      // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
      // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
      // delegation:
      // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
      .setSubject(email)

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
      // setup of domain-wide delegation.
      .setScope(scope);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a [Method: users.settings.sendAs.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/create) this is going to try to create a new one based upon the usersId, as far as i can tell from the docs you can only have one.

```
POST https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/sendAs
```

Which will most likely fail if the user already has one set.

I would try doing a [sendAs List](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/list) to see if the user has one set then if they do a  [users.settings.sendAs.patch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/patch) to reset what every they have set personally.  If they dont then use your create method.

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot. Now I have another thing, I'm trying to display my profile photo but the api return a private url(It return a default user image), do you know how to display my profile image?

Comment: Normally you go though the people api for profile information.    Or you can try the userinfo endpoint, but the data coming back from that isnt as good.  Give it a try and open a new question if you have isues.